# Can not click on Login button using xpath link

Tags: webdriver

Trying to click on Login button with the following in html page with webdriverio:

```html
<a id="btnLogin" class="big-button lnkbuttonlogin" href="javascript:__doPostBack('btnLogin','')" style="display:inline-block;width:173px;float:right; margin-left:15px; margin-bottom:15px;">
  <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-lock fa-w-14" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fa" data-icon="lock" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M400 224h-24v-72C376 68.2 307.8 0 224 0S72 68.2 72 152v72H48c-26.5 0-48 21.5-48 48v192c0 26.5 21.5 48 48 48h352c26.5 0 48-21.5 48-48V272c0-26.5-21.5-48-48-48zm-104 0H152v-72c0-39.7 32.3-72 72-72s72 32.3 72 72v72z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> -->&nbsp;Login
</a>
```

Using `const elem = $('//a[@id="btnLogin"]'); elem.click();`
That does not work. Need a way to select ID only. I have tried a few ways but every time everything is selected

Comment: <a id="btnLogin" class="big-button lnkbuttonlogin" href="javascript:__doPostBack('btnLogin','')"

Comment: If in XPATH id or class or href is used, everything is selected in html id and class and href.  How to write XPATH to just for ID.

Answer (score 0):

Use below xpath to select any element with an id
"//*[@id="btnLogin"]